# Difference between map, lmap, and imap in tidyverse (purrr package)?

Tags: r, functional-programming, tidyverse, purrr

I am a R user. I mainly use basic apply functions in R. However, I found purrr package interesting, but I could not differentiate between functions **map, lmap, and imap**. I would be grateful if someone can differentiate the functions with some examples. I tried the purrr package reference, but I couldn't make sense of the actual differences between them. Thanks.

Comment: Please correct the multiple missspleddings of the package name.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I changed them.

Answer (score 3):

1. map: maps over the elements, working the function on each.
2. imap: like map except you get the index or name of th element also.
3. lmap: maps over the elements, requires that they are in a list, and works the function on each as a one-element list

See:

```
# map:

> foo <- map( c(6:8), ~ print( .x ) )
[1] 6
[1] 7
[1] 8

# imap:
> foo <- imap( c(6:8), ~ print( c(.x,.y) ) )
[1] 6 1
[1] 7 2
[1] 8 3

# lmap:
> foo <- lmap( c(6:8), ~ print( c(.x) ) ) ## ERROR!
> foo <- lmap( as.list(6:8), ~ print(.x) )
[[1]]
[1] 6

[[1]]
[1] 7

[[1]]
[1] 8

## imap with names instead:
> foo <- imap( myvector, ~ cat( paste(.x,.y), "\n" ) )
6 a 
7 b 
8 c
```

Note `lmap` also works on data.frames (which are essentially lists). This can be very useful, consider the following:

```
## map:

> foo <- map( head(iris,n=3), print )
[1] 5.1 4.9 4.7
[1] 3.5 3.0 3.2
[1] 1.4 1.4 1.3
[1] 0.2 0.2 0.2
## -> each iteration gets a vector

## and with lmap:
> foo <- lmap( head(iris,n=3), print )
  Sepal.Length
1          5.1
2          4.9
3          4.7
  Sepal.Width
1         3.5
2         3.0
3         3.2
  Petal.Length
1          1.4
2          1.4
3          1.3
  Petal.Width
1         0.2
2         0.2
3         0.2
  Species
1  setosa
2  setosa
3  setosa
## -> each iteration gets a 1-column data.frame (which is useful when you need that)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I dont think I understand why you would use lmap. is it to make sure that input is a list, just like the map_chr() make sure that the output is , for example, a character vector?

Comment: no, it's to have the index of each element, as well as the actuall element. sometimes you need to know which item number you are processing, as well as the item itself